# How do I prevent the price in a configurable product’s attribute dropdown from changing?

Tags: magento

I have a configurable product with a Size dropdown. The values are Small, Medium, Large, X-Large. The prices for the sizes are $25, $30, $35, and $40. When I change the dropdown on the frontend (product page), all the options in the dropdown change to reflect the price difference. So when I change the dropdown to Large, the Small options says “Small -$10.00”, Medium says “Medium -$5.00”, and X-Large says “X-Large +$5.00”.

I want to prevent the pricesfrom updating and just show the product’s price. So Small will always say “Small - $25”, Medium will always say “Medium - $30”, and so on.

Could somebody please tell me how to do this?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product And try to use price fixed

Comment: I'm using fixed prices.